# repeat data on Ionic view?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

Database :

```
`--> product table
id  name      cid     uploadKey
1   Cemera     1       7365
2   Notebook   2       7222`

`--> category table
id    catename
1      canon
2      toshiba`


`--> attactments table
id      uploadKey       filepath
1       7365            /img/jdf.png
2       7365            /img/sdsd.jpg`
```

This code to create json file:

```
$_GET['id']="1";
 $json_response = array();
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $id=$_GET['id'];        
 $select = mysql_query("SELECT product.name,category.catename,attactments.filepath FROM product INNER JOIN category ON category.id = product.cid INNER JOIN attactments ON attactments.uploadKey = product.uploadKey where product.id='".$id."'  ");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select , MYSQL_ASSOC)) {       
        $json_response[] = $row;
         } 
    }
 echo $val= str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode($json_response));
```

The result repeat information, how to remove repeat i want to show as below :

```
[{"name":"Cemera","catename":"canon","filepath":"/img/jdf.png"},{"name":"Cemera","catename":"canon","filepath":"/img/sdsd.jpg"}]
```

Code ionic show detail:

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list class="list-inset">
            <ion-item class="item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="x in detail  ">
              <p> Name : {{x.name}}</p>

                <p>  Category : {{x.catename}}</p>
                 <p>  Filepath : {{x.filepath}}</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
</ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The result in ionic show like this how solve this problem

[image: the result]

I want to show like this:

```
  Name: Cemera
  Category : canon
  Filepath : /img/jdf.png
             /img/sdsd.jpg`
```

Comment: why   are you  sending then  all  data group by name and category and send from   server

Comment: If you  cannot  group  on server side just try    this angular  filter  https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

Comment: i didn't know how to do it, can u suggestion me

Comment: I have given you the link ..read it

Comment: i cant can u give me, the easy guide way